# searchBar with scopeBar weird behaviour

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I got problem with searchBar and scopeBar. Bascialy as soon as I click "cancel" and set `searchBar.showsScopeBar = false`, got this weird space left when next time searchBar is showing up.

Some code here:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultSearchController = ({

        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true

        controller.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal

        controller.searchBar.delegate = self
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()
```

and logic behind showing and hiding scope bar:

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Hot", "Active", "Warm"]
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit();
    return true
}


func searchBarShouldEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = false
    return true
}
```

And this is what is happening:

[image]

I could live with the scopeBar bar always visible, but then when during creation pops in before searchBar, when I go into details it falls below. So it's even worse than now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the scope bar during the creation of UISearchController itself (it will be visible only when the search bar is active). You don't need to manually show or hide the scope bar.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultSearchController = ({

        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true

        controller.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal

        controller.searchBar.delegate = self
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        controller.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Hot", "Active", "Warm"]
        definesPresentationContext = true

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but i'm getting something like that ![overlap](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90480/Screenshot%202015-05-14%2012.08.49.png)

Answer (score 2):

Late seeing this one but in case anyone else comes upon this. Removing these two lines below from @Slavomir code should give you the results you are looking for since there is no need to set showsScopeBar.

`self.resultSearchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true` //Remove
`self.resultSearchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = false` //Remove